# Extract Pandas Columns between two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have data as follows. First 2 columns are strings and columns names of columns df[3:60] as consecutive Year. How can I extract all the columns with years between 2005: 2010 and 2015 to everything

```
Country Indicator 1960    1961  1962    1963.....
Aruba    US$      15678 156789  156790  156791
Afgha    US$      68239 78239   88239   98239
Angola   US$      45678 55678   65678   75678
Albania  US$      89345 99345   109345  119345
Andorra  US$      62790 72790   82790   92790
Arab     US$     12987  22987   32987   42987
UAE      US$      6047  16047   26047   36047
```

I tried extracting index of columns

```
df.index.get_loc('2005') <- 45
df.index.get_loc('2010') <- 50
df.index.get_loc('2015') <- 55

df.iloc[:, [45:50,55:]]
```

The above code shows an error. How can I extract multiple columns with index ranging

Comment: Define a variable `col_range` as ```col_range = list(range(2005, 2011))```. Now use - ```df.loc[:, col_range]```, which will give you a dataframe with just the columns 2005...2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`np.r_`**:

```
a = df.columns.get_loc('2005')
b = df.columns.get_loc('2010')
c = df.columns.get_loc('2015')

df.iloc[:,np.r_[a-1:b,c-1:len(df.columns)]]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ab') +
                [*map(str,pd.date_range('2000','2021',freq='y').year)])
print(df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005,
         2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
         2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
Index: []
```

---

```
print(df.iloc[:,np.r_[a-1:b,c-1:len(df.columns)]])

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
Index: []
```

Comment: this solution is pretty elegant

Answer (score 1):

I think @anky's use of [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) is the right way to go and pretty flexible, this answer is just an alternative, using pandas builtin index method:

NB: i'm using @anky's example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ab') +
                [*map(str,pd.date_range('2000','2021',freq='y').year)])
```

use [slice_indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.slice_indexer.html#pandas.Index.slice_indexer) to get the slice locations of the interested values :

```
A = df.columns.slice_indexer('2005','2010')
A
slice(7, 13, None)
#if one entry is included, it includes the location of the last index
B = df.columns.slice_indexer('2015')
B
slice(17, 23, None)
```

add the [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) indexing of both A and B:

```
res = df.iloc[:,A] + df.iloc[:,B]
res
Index(['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2015', '2016', '2017',
       '2018', '2019', '2020'],
      dtype='object')
```

also note that @anky's method will be more efficient, since the iloc is called only once. again, this is just a play with the available methods

of course, you can combine [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) with the [slices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) of A and B:

```
res = df.iloc[:,np.r_[A,B]]
res.columns
Index(['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2015', '2016', '2017',
       '2018', '2019', '2020'],
      dtype='object')
```